# Song in episode 14 of Ghost in the shell SAC 2nd gig

Tags: music, ghost-in-the-shell-sac

The song is played right at the beginning of the flashback, when the soldiers are walking through the ruins.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but is it, [From the Roof Top ~ Somewhere in the Silence (Sniper’s Theme)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8OVH5AsuQA) ?

[List of Albums for Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Stand_Alone_Complex#Ghost_in_the_Shell:_S.A.C._2nd_GIG)

Useful links for previewing the ost's,

[link 1](http://www.jameswong.com/ykproject/disc/music.php)

[link 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/ghost-in-shell-stand-alone-complex-solid-state-society/423773033)

I think YouTube also got most of the OST's from the series but, I am not sure if it is available to your location.